# How to perform bulk insert into multilple tables which are related with foreign keys using entity framework

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I have to perform bulk insert(around 50-100 rows) into multiple tables( around 30 tables),
among them some tables are interrelated with foreign keys. 
I want to do this by using entity framework(EF).
But i want this happened with minimum db hit instead to of calling context.SaveChanges() for each table. Is there any way in EF to perform this? If it so please let me know.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940225/fastest-way-of-inserting-in-entity-framework

Comment: Impossible to answer this without seeing the actual case in code.

Comment: Here one sample case..

Comment: Here one sample case.. There are 4 tables [A,B,C ,D]  A and B are inter related with FK and C and D are interrelated with FK. I want to insert  100 records into all 4 tables. What is the best way to perform this in EF.

Comment: What makes you think you should call *SaveChanges() for each table*? It's simple. To stay in the same generic terms as you choose to describe your problem: add As, Bs, Cs, and Ds to their respective DbSets and call `SaveChanges` *once*.

Answer (score 0):

`Entity Framework` doesn't provide a `Bulk` feature.

For every row you want to save, a database round-trip is required.

---

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of [Entity Framework Extensions](http://entityframework-extensions.net/)

This library is not free but allows you to perform a `BulkSaveChanges` which work like `SaveChanges` but faster:

- Bulk SaveChanges
- Bulk Insert
- Bulk Delete
- Bulk Update
- Bulk Merge

Example

```
// Easy to use
context.BulkSaveChanges();

// Easy to customize
context.BulkSaveChanges(bulk => bulk.BatchSize = 100);

// Perform Bulk Operations
context.BulkDelete(customers);
context.BulkInsert(customers);
context.BulkUpdate(customers);

// Customize Bulk Operations
context.BulkInsert(customers, options => {
   options => options.IncludeGraph = true;
});
context.BulkMerge(customers, options => {
   options.ColumnPrimaryKeyExpression = 
        customer => customer.Code;
});
```